# Eclipse -vm option trouble

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm having trouble setting up a new eclipse installation with the -vm option. I'm using the eclipse.ini file below (which has worked in the past). I need this for the m2eclipse plugin. Currently, if I include the -vm option eclipse fails to start.

Any idea what the problem is with this?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: first try forward slashes, and then see some tips here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958601/eclipse-shows-splash-screen-and-closes-how-to-fix

Comment: I didn't have any luck w/ any of the suggestions in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a 64bit version of Eclipse with a 32bit JVM?

Comment: The JDK is 64 bit, but I have a 32bit version of Eclipse. I'm grabbing the 64 bit eclipse right now to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Seems like the 64 bit JDK along with the 64 bit eclipse is working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing its the space in the `Program Files` part of the path.  The below example works fine for me.  Can you try to install the JDK in c:/apps and see if the script below works for you?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-vm
C:/apps/jdk1.6.0_15/bin/javaw.exe
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-server
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms1200m
-Xmx1200m
```

Comment: Arguments in the eclipse.ini file are separated by newlines so the space there is fine.